# Postgresql после переустановки отказался работать

Tags: postgresql, windows-8

Сперва всё было хорошо. Преустановил Postgresql и после этого -не запускается.
Пишет

> Server doesn't listen The server doesn't accept connections: the
>   connection library reports  could not connect to server: Connection
>   refused (0x0000274D/10061)  Is the server running on host "localhost"
>   (::1) and accepting TCP/IP  connections on port 5433? could not
>   connect to server: Connection      refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the
>   server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1)  and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432?

По форумам посмотрел-такое бывает, но не нашёл- что с этим делать? 
Службу перезапускаю- она тут-же выключается 
OC Windows 8

Comment: Windows 7 - наблюдаю похожую проблему (на одной машине работает - на другой нет). Можно попробовать установить более старую версию Postgresq. Альтернативный вариант состоит в использовании виртуальной машины с линуксом, если это приемлемо в данном случае.

Comment: [раз](http://www.fryan0911.com/2010/08/postgresql-could-not-connect-to-server.html). [два](http://postgresql.ru.net/node/214756). Погуглите подобную проблему, вариантов может быть много. Пробуйте их до тех пор, пока не исправите. И сами же напишите ответ на свой вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Вы привели информацию о том, что сервер не запущен. Теперь главное — выяснить, что происходит при попытке запуска. Вот тут рекомендации, как вытащить эту информацию на Windows: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Troubleshooting_Installation#Extra_information_Windows_users_need_to_collect

Прежде всего нужно смотреть в Windows Event Log — с помощью Event Viewer. Скорее всего, там будет описана причина незапуска.

Answer (score 0):

Рассмотрите возможность проверки какой тип IP адреса получает база данных. Вижу что у вас включён IpV6, возможно стоит исключить выдачу диапазона Ipv6.
Так же я бы проверил запустилась ли сама база данных, у меня такое было из за долгого запуска базы, django требовал подключение быстрее чем мог позволить себе psql